# Tableview.reloadData deletes first row of tableView. Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, reloaddata

So I have a tableview which is meant to look like this.

[image]

and have the following code in place in my viewWillAppear function.

```
if (!self.isMovingToParentViewController){

        self.categoryDisplayed = ""
        self.collectionsDisplayed = ""
        self.currencyDisplayed = ""
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
```

to clear and reload the tableview, however then, the tableview ends up looking like this.

I dont know why this is happening, can someone help please :(

This is my cellForRowAt code:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listCell", for: indexPath) as! ListDataTableViewCell

    cell.dataTitleLabel.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]

    if indexPath.row == 0{
        cell.methodType.isHidden = true
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
        cell.optionSelectedLabel.isHidden = false
        cell.optionSelectedLabel.text! = categoryDisplayed
        cell.optionSelectedLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell.methodType.isHidden = false
        cell.methodType.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.74, blue:0.63, alpha:1.0)
        cell.optionSelectedLabel.isHidden = true
        cell.accessoryType = .none
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

    } else if indexPath.row == 2{
        cell.methodType.isHidden = true
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
        cell.optionSelectedLabel.isHidden = false
        cell.optionSelectedLabel.text! = currencyDisplayed
        cell.optionSelectedLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell.optionSelectedLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2

    } else if indexPath.row == 3{
        cell.methodType.isHidden = true
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
        cell.optionSelectedLabel.isHidden = false
        cell.optionSelectedLabel.text! = collectionsDisplayed

    }
    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: A posible solution depends on the code in `cellForRow...` and the kind of the data source array.

Comment: Can you add your `cellForRowAt:` implementation?

Comment: I have added my cellForRowAt: code

Comment: Cells are reused. You have to make sure that every UI element is set to a defined state. The cells seem to be static. Why don't you use *static cells*? The benefit is you are able to access all UI elements with `IBOutlet`s

Comment: But then how come it doesn't happen to the other cells?